# How do I place two text fields side by side?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a form for a landing page, so I want to keep the text input field side by side so I don't make the form very long.I trying to do something like this :

[image]

But it seems really difficult right now, this is what my form current looks like:

```css
.teaser-right {
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 3% 0 0 0
}

#calltoaction-form {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  position: right;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="calltoaction-form" class="teaser-form">
  <div class="form-title">
    <h3>sample form</h3>
  </div>
  <form id="contact_form" action="_contact-us.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-header">
      <h4>Personal details</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form-section">
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-section">
      <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email">
    </div>
```

Comment: Not a single element in the HTML you have shown has the class `teaser-right` - so how do you expect that rule in your CSS to take any effect?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.form-section{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To put 2 input fields beside each other you can use of float. if you float the elements you need to make sure you use the clearfix hack on the parent div. Otherwise the parent div won't have a height.

Another option is to use `display: inline-block` If you use display inline-block you need to reset the font-size on the parent to 0. The elements that where you use display: inline-block need to get the `font-size: 12px;` for example. With display inline-block you can get a slight height difference.

Example:

```
float: left;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ymma61hu/3/

Clearfix hack:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Example 2:

```
display: inline-block;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vh49gtzL/

Answer (score 0):

Hi just put input elements inside same div see fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/v5omym1a/

```
<div id="calltoaction-form" class="teaser-form">
  <div class="form-title">
    <h3>sample form</h3>
  </div>
  <form id="contact_form" action="_contact-us.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-header">
      <h4>Personal details</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form-section">
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
       <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email">
    </div>
```

Comment: Alternatively if you where open to using bootstrap you could use the inline-form...https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your markup a bit. You don't need to wrap your `<h3>` and `<h4>` in *div*-s - those are block level elements as well and can be perfectly styled.

```css
#calltoaction-form {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  position: right;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form-section {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}
```

```html
  <div id="calltoaction-form" class="teaser-form">
    <h3 class="form-title">sample form</h3>

    <form id="contact_form" action="_contact-us.php" method="post">

      <h4 class="form-header">Personal details</h4>

      <div class="form-section">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-section">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email">
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I kind of messed up by not putting up the complete code, its actually a form that has five elements / attributes. It might appear organized in jsfiddle but its really messy when its on the page as it doesn't align properly jsfiddle.net/ohgoody/ujaeoedb/2/ , screenshot : http://i.imgur.com/pWtRSCy.jpg

Comment: you need to clear the element you don't want to float (*upload your screenshot*) - http://jsfiddle.net/ujaeoedb/3/

Comment: I was actually talking about the form area with 3 drop down lists. I am still having some problems with that http://jsfiddle.net/ohgoody/pakawc9h/, [img]http://i.imgur.com/LojiCjw.jpg?1[/img]

Comment: can ypu add the relevant CSS to the fiddle, so I can fix it up? right now it looks very different from what you have on the image

Comment: Ok, I have added the relevant CSS and also more contents to the form so you can have a better picture. http://jsfiddle.net/ohgoody/pakawc9h/2/

Comment: Have you seen the new fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/zbfw3yzL/, see this also - http://jsfiddle.net/6ky3dw6s/

Comment: hey, in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ohgoody/pakawc9h/2/ everything looks like you wanted :) center aligned sub-titles, inputs nicely aligned..

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form-section {
      float: left;
      margin: 1%;
      width: 48.5%;
  }
  .form-section input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .form-section:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .form-section:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
#calltoaction-form {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: right;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="calltoaction-form" class="teaser-form">
  <div class="form-title">
    <h3>sample form</h3>
  </div>
  <form id="contact_form" action="_contact-us.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-header">
      <h4>Personal details</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container">
      <div class="form-section">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-section">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email">
      </div>
    </div>
```